# Can I have a function within a SELECT query?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, etl

Can I have a function within select statement like this?

```
select
myseq.nextval,
getDoctor(dbNumber,C.code,DOCCODE), 
getDoctor(dbNumber,C.code,RFDOCCODE), 
...
from charges c
where type='R';
```

Here getdoctor points to a function that checks two tables and returns a value:

```
create or replace function getDoctor(dbNumber IN NUMBER,code IN VARCHAR2(10),doccode IN VARCHAR2(10), OUT DOCID VARCHAR2(10))  
is 
begin
 DOCID:= nvl((select MDOCID from NEW_PROVIDERS NP where dbNumber=NP.dbNumber and code=NP.code and doccode=NP.doccode),
    select MDOCID from ProvidersProxy P where P.originalDB=dbNumber and code=P.originalGroup and doccode=P.originalDocCode);
return DOCID;
end getDoctor;
```

Comment: Are you asking this because you're getting some sort of error? If so, please edit the question and include the errors you're getting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this (don't forget about the "p_" prefixes):

```
create or replace function getDoctor(
    p_dbNumber IN NUMBER,
    p_code IN VARCHAR2(10),
    p_doccode IN VARCHAR2(10)
) return varchar2
is
  l_DOCID VARCHAR2(10);
begin
  begin
    select MDOCID
      into l_DOCID 
      from NEW_PROVIDERS NP 
     where p_dbNumber=NP.dbNumber 
       and p_code=NP.code 
       and p_doccode=NP.doccode
    ;
  exception
    when no_data_found then
      select MDOCID 
        into l_DOCID
        from ProvidersProxy P 
       where P.originalDB=p_dbNumber 
         and p_cpcode=P.originalGroup 
         and p_doccode=P.originalDocCode
      ;
  end;
  return l_DOCID;
end getDoctor;
```

Comment: Functions to be used in SQL statements don't use `OUT` parameters. You need to include the `RETURNS` datatype clause, and you need to then return something in the statement.

Answer (score 0):

The basic signature for an Oracle SQL usable function (which is well documented everywhere), is of the form:

```
FUNCTION my_function (param1 datatype, param2 datatype)
RETURN datatype
IS
local_variable1 datatype;
local_variable2 datatype;
BEGIN
-- Do something awesome
return local_variable;
/* Optional Exceptions Block */
END;
```

So in your case (with some rewriting of the `NVL()`) then:

```
create or replace function getDoctor(p_dbNumber IN NUMBER, p_code IN VARCHAR2, p_doccode IN VARCHAR2)
return varchar2
is 
DOCID VARCHAR2(10);
begin

  select MDOCID into DOCID 
  from NEW_PROVIDERS NP 
  where p_dbNumber=NP.dbNumber 
  and p_code=NP.code 
  and p_doccode=NP.doccode;

return DOCID;
EXCEPTION
 when no_data_found then
    select MDOCID INTO DOCID 
    from ProvidersProxy P 
    where P.originalDB=p_dbNumber 
    and p_code=P.originalGroup 
    and p_doccode=P.originalDocCode;

    return DOCID;

end getDoctor;
```

Comment: You will have `TOO_MANY_ROWS`, because the tables NEW_PROVIDERS and ProvidersProxy have columns dbNumber, cpcode, doccode (it is like you write `WHERE 1 = 1`), you have to use different names for the parameters of the getDoctor function.

Comment: Thus spoke @zaratustra, you are correct! In my copy and paste haste I overlooked good variable naming practices.

Comment: Also you forgot to add the exception word right above `when no_data_found`